# What is the name for a solution where multiple sites point to a single back-end domain?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

We are looking to build a back-end application that multiple school web sites can point to.  I would like to advertise this service correctly but I am not sure of the name to use for this service.

Does anyone have any advice to offer that would help me?

Comment: Please describe this back end more clearly.   There are several possible back-end relationships with different names.   Are you providing an API?   Are you make a white label product?   Are you offering embeddable content?